# draw a line into a mapsforge-map

Tags: android

I want to draw a line (connecting some LatLong-coordinates) into a mapsforge-map.
But I don't know how to create an overlay for the latLongs-list and connecting the overlay with the map.
I'm using mapsforge 0.5.0 and have included:
mapsforge-map-android-0.5.0.jar, mapsforge-map-0.5.0.jar,
mapsforge-core-android-0.5.0.jar, mapsforge-map-reader-0.5.0.jar

The mapfile exists on the sdcard and is displayed.

The code:

```
 package com.example.ad.mapsforge;

 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Environment;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;

 import org.mapsforge.core.graphics.GraphicFactory;
 import org.mapsforge.core.graphics.Paint;
 import org.mapsforge.core.graphics.Style;
 import org.mapsforge.core.model.LatLong;
 import org.mapsforge.map.android.graphics.AndroidGraphicFactory;
 import org.mapsforge.map.android.graphics.AndroidResourceBitmap;
 import org.mapsforge.map.android.util.AndroidUtil;
 import org.mapsforge.map.android.view.MapView;
 import org.mapsforge.map.layer.cache.TileCache;
 import org.mapsforge.map.layer.overlay.Polyline;
 import org.mapsforge.map.layer.renderer.TileRendererLayer;
 import org.mapsforge.map.rendertheme.InternalRenderTheme;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.util.List;

 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   // name of the map file in the external storage
   private static final String MAPFILE = "saarland.map";//sachsen-anhalt.map";
   private MapView mapView;
   private TileCache tileCache;
   private TileRendererLayer tileRendererLayer;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     AndroidGraphicFactory.createInstance(this.getApplication());

     this.mapView = new MapView(this);
     setContentView(this.mapView);

     this.mapView.setClickable(true);
     this.mapView.getMapScaleBar().setVisible(true);
     this.mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
     this.mapView.getMapZoomControls().setZoomLevelMin((byte) 10);
     this.mapView.getMapZoomControls().setZoomLevelMax((byte) 20);

     // create a tile cache of suitable size
     this.tileCache = AndroidUtil.createTileCache(this, "mapcache",
             mapView.getModel().displayModel.getTileSize(), 1f,
             this.mapView.getModel().frameBufferModel.getOverdrawFactor());
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
     super.onStart();

     GraphicFactory gf=AndroidGraphicFactory.INSTANCE;
     Paint paint=gf.createPaint();
 //    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
     paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
     paint.setStrokeWidth(7);
     paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

     this.mapView.getModel().mapViewPosition.setCenter(new LatLong(49.2333, 7.0));
     this.mapView.getModel().mapViewPosition.setZoomLevel((byte) 12);

     // tile renderer layer using internal render theme
     this.tileRendererLayer = new TileRendererLayer(tileCache,
             this.mapView.getModel().mapViewPosition, false,true, AndroidGraphicFactory.INSTANCE);
     tileRendererLayer.setMapFile(getMapFile());
     tileRendererLayer.setXmlRenderTheme(InternalRenderTheme.OSMARENDER);
     Polyline pl=new Polyline(paint,gf);
     List latLongs=pl.getLatLongs();
     latLongs.add(new LatLong(49.2333, 7.0));
     latLongs.add(new LatLong(49.2333, 7.02));

     // only once a layer is associated with a mapView the rendering starts
     this.mapView.getLayerManager().getLayers().add(tileRendererLayer);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     this.mapView.getLayerManager().getLayers().remove(this.tileRendererLayer);
     this.tileRendererLayer.onDestroy();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     this.tileCache.destroy();
     this.mapView.getModel().mapViewPosition.destroy();
     this.mapView.destroy();
     AndroidResourceBitmap.clearResourceBitmaps();
   }

   private File getMapFile() {
     File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), MAPFILE);
     return file;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
     return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     int id = item.getItemId();

     //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
     if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
       return true;
     }

     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
 }
```

Please help !

Regards Wicki

Comment: Now I have added the following statement at the end of onStart and it's working: this.mapView.getLayerManager().getLayers().add(pl);

Answer (score 0):

from graphhopper source:

```
private Polyline createPolyline(GHResponse response) 
{
        Paint paintStroke = Utils.createPaint(AndroidGraphicFactory.INSTANCE
                .createColor(org.mapsforge.core.graphics.Color.GREEN), 1,
                Style.STROKE);
        paintStroke.setDashPathEffect(new float[] { 25, 15 });
        paintStroke.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paintStroke.setStrokeWidth(3);
        Polyline line = new Polyline(paintStroke,
                AndroidGraphicFactory.INSTANCE);

        List<LatLong> geoPoints = line.getLatLongs();
        PointList tmp = response.getPoints();
        for (int i = 0; i < response.getPoints().getSize(); i++) {
            geoPoints.add(new LatLong(tmp.getLatitude(i), tmp.getLongitude(i)));

        }

        return line;

}
```

Adjust it to your needs...